# Hi I am new in python and I want to add one extra columns with saved file name when merging the all excel file from a folder in python

Tags: python

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
path = "C:/Users/kbisht/Downloads/AIR REPORT/Consolidated sentinal Hospital"

file_list = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")

excl_list = []

for file in file_list: 
    
    excl_list.append(pd.read_excel(file))

excl_merged = pd.DataFrame()

for excl_file in excl_list:

  excl_merged = excl_merged.append(excl_file, ignore_index=True)

excl_merged.to_excel('Consolidated_sentinal_kuber5.xlsx', index=False)
```

I want a separate columns with "saved files name" when merging the all excel file in python, so I can short the data with given file name.

Comment: Have you tested the [approach below](/a/77278364/16343464)? Any feedback?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `append` in a loop, use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and make the container a dictionary to have the file names (with `names=['filename']` to define a future column name), [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and pipe it directly to [`to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
file_list = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")

(pd.concat({name: pd.read_excel(name) for name in file_list},
           names=['filename'])
   .reset_index('filename')
   .to_excel('Consolidated_sentinal_kuber5.xlsx', index=False)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I modify your code to include information.

**Here's how I tried :**

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os
```

**path**

path = "C:/Users/kbisht/Downloads/AIR REPORT/Consolidated sentinal Hospital"

**Now**

```
file_list = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")
excl_list = []

for file in file_list:
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    file_name = file.split("\\")[-1]
    df['File_Name'] = file_name
    excl_list.append(df)
excl_merged = pd.concat(excl_list, ignore_index=True)
excl_merged.to_excel('Consolidated_sentinal_kuber5.xlsx', index=False)
```

The appropriate file names for each row will be contained in the "File Name" column that this code will construct in the combined DataFrame. This data will be a part of the output when saving the combined data to the Excel file.

Comment: This won't work, you'll just make the file names and actual data out of sync

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I edited my code. @mozway

Comment: don't take this bad but have you used an AI tool to assist you in writing this answer? I have some reasons to believe so

Comment: Hi Nayem, The code is running but I need the file name should be repeated in every row which are related to that file. suppose if a file have 50 rows and another file has 100 rows  then the name of the file should be repeated the all 50 rows and another 100 rows for another file and so on.